# How long does it take to charge a Mastercraft 7.2V cordless drill?

Tags: tools

I don't have the booklet that came with this Craftmaster 7.2V cordless drill. I am not sure of time to charge the battery but I assume it should be at least 3 hours or more.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

It is going to depend on a couple factors - how deeply the battery is discharged, the temperature of the battery, and the condition of the battery itself.  I'd just leave it on the charger until the charge light goes off.

For other battery tips including some notes on charging, see [this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3128/what-type-of-cordless-tool-battery-chemistry-should-i-purchase/3129#3129).

Comment: Please don't perpetuate Ni-Cad myths. Unless you happen to have your Ni-Cads on a satellite that charges them just so much in the sunshine and then uses just this other amount when the sun is out of sight, Ni-Cad memory is mostly a myth, and more NiCads are harmed by people "trying to drain them fully" than ever had a memory issue... http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/memory_myth_or_fact

Comment: @Ecnerwal The article you link doesn't claim NiCads don't develop memory - in fact the opposite.  It just says that it isn't irreversible: "Recondition restores NiCd batteries with hard-to-remove memory."

Comment: It also does not suggest total discharge every time you charge - every 1-3 months, at most.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Fair enough, edited.

Comment: Plus the other evil that's worse than memory, most people believe in the memory mystery because they've left the Ni-Cds on the charger so long the batteries overheated and vented the water out of their electrolyte. Of course they fail when that happens. Over-charging has killed more NiCd batteries than memory ever did. Non-smart wallwart chargers being talked about here, the new ones with the charge cycle to trickle chipset don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate charge time, (with a non intelligent charger), you would need to look at the voltage output of the charger unit (as well as the charge current)

so the factors are: (excluding external factors) 
current flow coming in, size of battery, and level of discharge ..

Go onto this website with your parameters and it should tell you.
[battery charge calculator](https://www.easycalculation.com/physics/classical-physics/battery-charge.php)

I actually have 2 transformers with different voltages, which I plug into my charger dock. makes for some sort of "intelligent" charger.